# What is the best way to handle audit revision in Many-to-one relation entity in Hibernate envers?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have two entities **BusinessUnit.java** and **BusinessPartner.java** And I have a join entity **BusinessUnitPartnerMap.java**

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class BusinessUnit {

private int id;
private String unitName;
private String description;
private String status;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "businessPartner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<BusinessPartnerUnitMap> businessPartnerUnitMaps;

}


@Entity
@Audited
public class BusinessPartner {

private int id;
private String partnerName;
private String details;
private String status;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "businessPartner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<BusinessPartnerUnitMap> businessPartnerUnitMaps;

}

@Entity
@Audited
public class BusinessPartnerUnitMap {

 private int businessPartnerUnitMapId;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "business_partner_id")
 private BusinessPartner businessPartner;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "business_unit_id")
 private BusinessUnit businessUnit;

}
```

While Updating **BusinessPartner**, I am using **BusinessUnit DAO** and loading only Business Unit id & unitName.

As result in **business_unit_aud** table except id and unitName, all the values are inserting null because of **BusinessUnitPartnerMap**.

Is there any way to insert data in **business_unit_aud** table without loading the **BusinessUnit** object at the time of updating **BusinessPartner** ?

Comment: *loading only Business Unit id & unitName.* I am not sure I understand what you mean here. You need to add the relevant code, which is that which loads, modifies and saves the entity.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are maintaining @ManyToMany relationship. If you switch to

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class BusinessPartner {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(
            name = "BusinessUnit", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "business_partner_id") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "business_unit_id") 
    })
    private List<BusinessPartnerUnit> businessPartnerUnits;
}
```

With Lazy initialization, you don't have to load referenced data and it will not replaced with nulls; and @ManyToMany will allow you to keep the relationship without having an extra entity. 
If this doesn't help, i'll need to know how do you load entities in BusinessUnitDAO